# Do we need the shutdown tag?

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

There are [206 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shutdown) marked with [shutdown](/questions/tagged/shutdown).

These are related to killing servers, scripts or applets.

There doesn't seem to be a consensus around it, and other tags (plus the title in most cases) explain the situation anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There may not be a consensus about what the tag is for, but that doesn't mean it's an inherently bad tag. It *does* provide some semantic information, and I *can* imagine people searching or categorizing questions using this tag. So I think we should keep it—or at least see little harm in keeping it around.

The best option if you want to clean things up is to go through the list of questions that have this tag (especially since it's a manageable number) and either re-tag the question to something more appropriate, remove the tag altogether, or note the most commonly-used cases or interpretations for the tag and add those to the tag wiki so that everyone knows what the tag is/should be used for.